# How to show sql request in JPA criteria

Tags: java, jpa, criteria

I am using `JPA criteria`, How show my sql native request via `CriteriaQuery<Object[]>` query in mode debug.

Comment: Show us configuration file xml?

Comment: set to `true` property `hibernate.show_sql` in persistence.xml for the persistense unit

Comment: programmatically? via log? which JPA implementation?

Comment: hibernate implementation, in mode debug, thanks